# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1600 input samples and 1800 target samples

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am following this tutorial here to do image classification.
Link: [Keras image classification](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

The code I am referencing is [Bottleneck feature](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/f35fbc80e066a49d65f1688a7e99f069)
The problem I am facing:
1. The original tutorial has only two classes but I am trying to do multi-class classification.
My file structure looks like:

```
data
  train
    class1
    class2
    class3
    class4
  test
    class1
    class2
    class3
    class4
```

The following code in the original code is for two class classification.

```
train_labels = np.array(
    [0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))

validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy'))
validation_labels = np.array(
    [0] * (nb_validation_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples / 2))
```

I understand that in order to multi-class classification I have to change it to:

```
train_labels = np.array(
    [0] * (class0_train_size) + [1] * (class1_train_size)+ [2] * (class2_train_size) + [3] * (class3_train_size))

validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy'))
validation_labels = np.array(
    [0] * (class0_test_size) + [1] * (class1_test_size)+ [2] * (class2_test_size) + [3] * (class3_test_size))
```

My question is my train test size vary for different classes so it's kind of hard for me to hardcode them. Is there a way I can allocate them dynamically based on the actual number of images inside a folder instead of hardcoding the size? Thanks for your generous help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility to get the prevalence of your different classes is to use the os library. For instance for the test classes, you can first get the list of classes in the test folder using :

```
import os

abs_path = "/bla/bla/test"
test_classes = [d for d in os.listdir(abs_path)]
```

You can get the number of files in each class directory and then store them using a dict or a list :

```
test_class_sizes = dict()
for c in classes:
    test_class_folder = os.path.join(abs_path, c)
    test_class_sizes[c] = len([d for d in os.listdir(test_class_folder)])
```

And finally you use this dict to construct your flat label list :

```
validation_labels = [[k]*class_size for k, class_size in enumerate(class_sizes)]
flattened_validatoin_labels = [label for class_list in validation_labels for label in class_list]
```

Comment: Thanks, would you mind clarify what is class_list and how you construct it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I messed up that line. I edited it. Class_list is just a sublist of validation_labels